# Getting an 'int' object is not subscriptable error when trying to calculate and print an integer

Tags: python, math, integer

I'm trying to write a simple program to calculate the Collatz COnjecture but I keep getting the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/457700/Desktop/collatzconjecture.py", line 11, in <module>
if int(n[-1]) == "0" or int(n[-1]) == "2" or int(n[-1]) == "4" or int(n[-1]) == "6" or int(n[-1]) == "8":
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, other similar posts on the site failed to resolve the issue. here's the rest of my code for context.

```
#This program will calculate the Collatz Conjecture

repeat = "y"

while repeat[0].lower() == "y":

     n = int(input("Enter n: "))

     while n != 1:

         if n[-1] == "0" or n[-1] == "2" or n[-1] == "4" or n[-1] == "6" or n[-1] == "8":
             n = n/2
             print(n)
     else:
         n = n * 3
         n = n + 1
         print(n)

repeat = input("Repeat? (Y/N): ")
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `n[-1]`? `n` in your program is an `int`, what should `n[-1]` be?

Comment: I see a few other issues as well. If you solve the current error, I see at least 2 infinite loops, assuming the indentation in this post is accurate to what is in your code

Comment: With your big `if` you want to check if the number is even in order to divide by 2? It seems that you want to check the last digit. Simply do `if n % 2 == 0`

Comment: `n[i]` does not give you the `i`th digit of a number. *Numbers* don't have digits; string representations *of* numbers do.

Comment: If you really wanted to go with the digit-checking approach, `bin(n)[-1] == '0'` is true iff `n` is even. That's approximately 3x slower than using `%`, though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `n` is an `int`, so you can only use `n[]` for data types that are subscritable like `lists`, `tuples`, `iterables` in general.

So if you just want to match the value: instead of `n[-1] == '0'` write `n == 0` and so on.

Comment: I want to check the last character of n to see if it is even. if it is even, n is divided by 2. If it is odd, n = 3(n)+1. This continues until n = 1. how do check the last character of n then convert it back to an integer for math?

Comment: Ok, the problem is that `n = int(input("Enter n: "))` makes `n` an integer, so you cannot use string methods. `input()` will return a string. You can just use `if n % 2:` to know if n is odd.